# Is there a way to define kotlin infix function precedence?

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin has infix functionality, which is great, but is there a way to alter precedence of them? In
[haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#infix.2C_infixl.2C_infixr) there's `infix`, `infixl` and `infixr` to have e.g.

```
class Num a where
  ...
  (*) :: a -> a -> a
  ...

infixl 7 *
```

Can kotlin do something similar (or is such planned for it)?

Comment: No, you can't change that. And I don't expect that to ever be a feature. Having custom precedence rules will make the code harder to read.

Comment: Mmmm.  There's a fairly common opinion to the effect that the _only_ precedence you should every rely on is that multiplication binds tighter than addition; and you should use brackets for absolutely everything else.  I don't agree with that -- I think there are many other common situations where knowledge of the language's rules is appropriate and makes the code clearer.  But having -- and especially relying on -- rules that aren't even part of the language, but only your own code, seems likely to be highly confusing and error-prone!